# How to know if I am running in an emulator or real mobile phone

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I would to like to know if Is there any to check if I am running the application in a emulator or real phone? I want to change some configuration when I am testing in the netbeans/emulador and when it goes to real mobile phone change to another configuration such as server address. Is there any java me function to check it?

Comment: You must write your solution and accept it for helping future views of the question. It's important accept an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this code.

```
String platform = System.getProperty("microedition.platform");
platform = platform.toUpperCase();
if ((platform.indexOf("J2ME") != -1) || (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("SunMicrosystems_wtk"))) {
 //EMULATOR
}else {
//Device
}
```

If you are using other emulator you can try doing System.out.println(platform) and see what print when yo are using on emulator

Comment: I afraid some unbranded phones returns j2me also. I was thinking to use System.getProperty("microedition.profiles") which returns me "MIDP-2.1 JAVAFX-1.1"

Comment: Really a use this: 

if (platform.indexOf("NOKIA") != -1) { //NOKIA; } else if (platform.indexOf("SAMSUNG") != -1) { //SAMSUNG; } else if (platform.indexOf("SONYERICSSON") != -1) { //SONY_ERICSSON; } else if (platform.indexOf("LG") != -1) { //LG; } else if ((platform.indexOf("BLACKBERRY") != -1) || (platform.indexOf("RIM") != -1)) { return BLACKBERRY; } else if ((platform.indexOf("J2ME") != -1) || (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("SunMicrosystems_wtk"))) { //EMULATOR; }

Comment: with this you filter before that devices

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property in JAD, and just change that property when you build for real device

for example :

```
device-name: emulator
```

and you can read it in MIDlet using

```
getAppProperty("device-name");
```

Comment: i think this is not a real solution, you change this manually and he want a function for doing it at code